Did Iranian missile strikes on Israel destroy any number of F-35s?

Forbes: Iranian Media Claims Israeli F-35 Fighters Destroyed In Missile Strike

Damage was also reported to be minimal, but on social media on Wednesday, many pro-Iranian supporters echoed reports from Iranian state media that the missiles successfully struck Israeli airbases. Claims were made that the attack destroyed entire squadrons of the Lockheed Martin F-35I Adir—the Israeli Air Force's fifth-generation fighter.



Did Iranian missile strikes on Israel destroy any number of F-35s?

Probably none, although there were some impacts on a hangar, but how are we going to be sure? Israel isn't going to do BDA for Iran publicly, besides what's already visible from commercial sats. Western opinion is that Israel had plenty of time to scramble their jets, given that they received warning from the US a few hours before the attack.

IIRC no other photos have been released except this one, from that base https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcDLYC-N-N8 The caveat is that that's on ly a portion of the base.

There is now a photo from another section,  a claimed hit on hardened shelter, https://youtu.be/zsipPfOswwQ?t=325 Unclear what if anything was inside at the time.

Higher res photos https://horsdoeuvresofbattle.blog/2024/10/04/imint-irans-strike-on-nevatim-airbase/

Here's a preliminary answer, based on publicly available information to date. The likelihood of IRGC's initial claim of having destroyed ~20 F-35s (later restated as just a "signficant number") seems quite low.

Israel's government publicly denied any were hit.

Based on the public record of announcements, Israel had a few hours warning from the US. They have a number of aerial refueling tankers, which would have allowed them to keep planes airborne for a good number of hours.

Open source satellite photos of Nevatim airbase (where the F-35's are normally stationed) show no direct signs of any airplane wreckage on the ground. And at most two impacts on aircraft storage facilities there:

One on a thinly roofed structure that was likely housing transport/surveillance/tanker aircraft in normal circumstances, due its proximity to the latter. That structure took clear damage from the impact/expulsion, but whether there was anything in/under it can't be easily assessed from satellite photos. 

And one in a hardened structure that is claimed to have housed F-35s. At least one open intel source claims the warhead (or object) hitting that didn't detonate. I'm not entirely sure that is correct, given that in demos of western "bunker buster" weapons, the impact point sometimes shows little else besides a small hole, but probably there should be signs of the pressure wave having come out somewhere, and that isn't visible in the photo in question.  





The interesting part is that the Iranian ballistic missiles were able to successfully penetrate the "Iron Dome" and thus can cause high civilian casualty if targeted at populous cities. More here - IMINT: Iran’s Strike on Nevatim Airbase.
